# How to Disable IconservicesAgent? I Don't use the GUI

Tags: macos, plist

IconservicesAgent is using 80-90% of my CPU, causing my macbook air 2018 to overheat just by turning it on.

I don't need this as I hardly use the GUI, I'm on the terminal 95% of the time, don't even use the browser.

---

All of the things in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107154/com-apple-iconservicesagent-using-a-lot-of-ram-in-10-9) don't prevent this Agent from eating the CPU. I don't need any of the 'benefits' of finder showing icons and I don’t have issues with RAM, it’s CPU I need to keep free for other tasks.

Besides this question clearly stated that I want the agent disabled.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151651/discussion-on-question-by-nickotine-how-to-disable-iconservicesagent-i-dont-us); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that it's easier (and better practice) to fix the high CPU usage problem, rather than just disable this process completely.

There are frequent references to this problem, with a number of solutions:

You could try deleting the iconServices cache:

```
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
```

... and similar folders:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ \( -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -or -name com.apple.iconservices \) -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

... and then restart.

Some people have reported that removing generated icons from Movie files may help:

```
find ~/Movies -name "*.mp4" | while read f ; 
do xattr -d com.apple.ResourceFork "$f" ; 
done
```

Comment: As was stated this process gives me no benefit, I don't use the GUI, however this looks to be the best suggestion so far, I'll look into it

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure you can easily disable this without third party software.

I would use the free trial of App Tamer to see if it’s capable of stopping all CPU use or throttling it in a manner you approve.

- https://stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/index.html

Finder is a big user of this daemon, but other apps and system services can also call it. I would get rid of everything from your dock and hide the dock to be sure it’s not downloads or another icon triggering a loop. Plus the normal triage steps of [restart in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) once, power off and [repair all your disks in recovery OS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102611). Then power off and on cleanly to retest.

Comment: is that a GUI app? No thank you Sir.

Comment: It’s an amazing piece of software for managing CPU and energy use tightly, but a pure command line existence can be super @Nickotine   I’m hoping the other answer fixes your issue and you can let the service run cleanly.

Comment: Thanks @bmike I think you've helped me in the past. It does seem quite helpful but it's a paid for app. There should be cmdline alternatives or maybe even a unix command that does the same thing, it's a good idea.